# Cuda mutex, why sometimes it need __threadfence()?

Tags: c++, cuda, mutex, atomic, memory-barriers

Here's a test kernel function that writes 1-10000 in `a`:

```
__global__ void write(int *count, int *a, int length, int *lock){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i == 0)
        *lock = 0;
    if(i < length){
        bool blocked = true;
        while(blocked) {
            if(0 == atomicCAS(lock, 0, 1)) {
                //*count = *count + 1;
                atomicAdd(count, 1);
                a[i] = *count;
                atomicExch(lock, 0);
                blocked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

write<<<(length + 31) / 32, 32>>>(dev_count, dev_a, length, lock);
```

When I replace `atomicAdd()` with `*count = *count + 1`, there will be repeated value in array `a`. But when I add `__threadfence()` before the `atomicExch` line, it works. In my real case, I add `__threadfence()` before **and** after the critical section like this:

```
__global__ void func(int length, int *lock){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i == 0)
        *lock = 0;
    if(i < length){
        bool blocked = true;
        while(blocked) {
            if(0 == atomicCAS(lock, 0, 1)) {
                __threadfence()
                /*
                    critical section
                */
                __threadfence()
                atomicExch(lock, 0);
                blocked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know why it needs `__threadfence()` and why it works.

Comment: If you need a mutex on a GPU, then something is definitively wrong. This is the worst possible thing on GPUs (especially if all threads are involved). Please reconsider the need for mutex. Cooperative (SIMT-friendly) multithreading is the key for performance, not mutual exclusion.

Comment: The logic behind `if(i == 0) *lock = 0;` is broken. Nothing guarantees that the 0-th thread can store the value before any other thread jumps into the first CAS

Comment: a mutex like this would typically be used to regulate access to data in global memory.  Presumably in the critical section, you are modifying data in global memory.  You want any other thread in the grid to be able to see the modifications that were made.  `__threadfence()` is part of that visibility strategy.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions)